# windows.location.href not working on Firefox3

Tags: javascript, firefox

We have a JavaScript function named "move" which does just "windows.location.href = *any given anchor*". 
This function works on IE, Opera and Safari, but somehow is ignored in Firefox. Researching on Google doesn't produce a satisfactory answer **why** it doesn't work. 
Does any JavaScript guru knows about this behavior, and what would be the best practice to jump to an anchor via JavaScript?

Comment: I just tried setting "window.location.href" on w3school's test page and it worked. Are you sure nothing else could be causing the problem? http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_location

Comment: Thanks for your post. 
Well, I tried to simplify the scenario. The whole picture is that we call the javascript from Response.Write, in an event coming from a DevExpress grid. That would be the whole context of the problem. Trying with only window.location didn't work.

Comment: not sure if I get this "calling it from Response.Write" bit.  If you are "echo"-ing it to the output, wrapped in a <script> tag, then it should work fine. is this what you are doing?

Comment: This is what I am doing: Response.Write("<script type='text/javaScript'> window.location.href = '#myAnchor'; </script>";);

Comment: It goes in a codebehind on the FocusedRowChanged event handler of a Devexpress grid

Comment: I tried this links and anchors example from w3schools http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_anchor1 
on FireFox 3 and did not work.

Comment: ah, ok, thats the issue, you are trying to set a hash, not a url, thus all you are telling the browser to do is to scroll to a spot on the page either with the id="myAnchor", or <a name="myAnchor".  If such a spot already exists in the DOM above where you are, it should scroll there, in the same pg.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345807/window-location-does-not-work-on-chrome-browser also

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Have you tried just using

```
window.location = 'url';
```

In some browsers, `window.location.href` is a read-only property and is not the best way to set the location (even though technically it should allow you to). If you use the `location` property on its own, that should redirect for you in all browsers.

Mozilla's documentation has a pretty detailed explanation of how to use the `window.location` object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

Comment: it is readonly in the sense that you can't change it, but setting a location.href is totally valid and works in all browsers (except in a cornercase scenario in IE6)

Comment: Setting `window.location` instead of `window.location.href` causes problems in some other browsers. (I don't rememeber exactly which at the moment, though.)

Comment: @Guffa If that's true, it's news to me. I don't know any browsers that have a problem setting the `location` object. I'd like to know what browsers can't, if you can find out...

Comment: @Craig As scunliffe pointed out, setting `window.location.href` will work, but not in IE6. Setting `window.location` works in all browsers that I've tested so far, however.

Comment: +1 for the updated post ;). My comment above is now irrelevant so I'll remove it.

Comment: @manakor I just tested it now. It worked fine for me in Firefox 4.

Comment: @scunliffe: I'm curious, what's the corner case on IE6? (If you happen to recall off the top of your head.) [This works on IE6](http://jsbin.com/awicib/2), but as you said corner case, I'm not too surprised that example doesn't replicate it.

Comment: Trying to recall the specifics (IE6 is mostly a horrible memory these days) but somewhat related I do recall this one: http://jvleminc.blogspot.ca/2008/03/ie6-locationhref-in-onclick-event-not.html that in turn points to this: http://webbugtrack.blogspot.ca/2007/09/bug-223-magical-http-get-requests-in.html where IE6 makes the HTTP request, adds it to your history, but doesn't actually go there and general IE bugs like not passing the referrer: http://webbugtrack.blogspot.ca/2008/11/bug-421-ie-fails-to-pass-http-referer.html

Comment: What is yout thought on the highest voted answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345807/window-location-does-not-work-on-chrome-browser ??  It tells we must not use window.location = 'url';

Comment: Solved my problem. I was using `location.replace('url');` and it worked on **Chrome** and **IE**, but not on **Firefox**. Changed to `window.location` and everything is as pretty as an avocado now :)

Answer (score 19):

If you are trying to call this javascript code after an event that is followed by a callback then you must add another line to your function:

```
function JSNavSomewhere()
{
    window.location.href = myUrl;
    return false;
}
```

in your markup for the page, the control that calls this function on click must return this function's value

```
<asp:button ........ onclick="return JSNavSomewhere();" />
```

The false return value will cancel the callback and the redirection will now work.  Why this works in IE?  Well I guess they were thinking differently on the issue when they prioritized the redirection over the callback.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks! this issue was driving me nuts until I found this ! +1 to you for saving my hairline.

Comment: Thanks for this, saved me some time.  IE6 always needs a special kick in the pants.

Answer (score 5):

One observation to ensure in such a scenario

Following will work in `IE`, but neither in `Chrome` nor in `Firefox` (the versions I tested)

```
 window.location.href("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

Following will work all the three

```
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Comment: I dont think window.location.href works reliably in Safari though

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's just a typo in your post and not in your code, but it's **window** and not **window*s***

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure to follow you.
I just tried: going with FF3 to [Lua 5.1 Reference Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html) (long and with lot of anchors).
Pasting `javascript:window.location.href="#2.5"; alert(window.location.href);` in the address bar, I went to the right anchor and it displayed the right URL. Works also with a full URL, of course.
Alternative code: `javascript:(function () { window.location.href="#2.5"; })();`

Perhaps you forgot the #. Common problem, also with image maps.

Comment: Thanks for your post. I set the # char too. Can you try without the "alert" sentence? If I put an alert, somehow it works, if I remove it, it doesn't.

Comment: If you remove it in the bookmarklet, you have to replace it with void(0) or put the whole stuff in a function call: the bookmarklet must not have a final value.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and I guess this is related to a **click event**.

I have a function that moves the browser to a specific page. I attach that function to some click events: in a button and in a image. AlsoI execute the function when the user press escape (document onkeypress event).

The results are that in all cases the function is called and executed, but only when there is a click the browser goes to the address I want.

**Update**
I got it working! with a

```
setTimeout( "location.replace('whatever.html');", 0 );
```

I don't know why the location.replace wasn't working when the event was a keypress, but with the settimeout it works :)

**Update**
Returning false after the event when you press escape makes the redirection works. If you return true or nothing the browser will not follow

Answer (score 2):

You've got to add **return false;** after the window.location.href as mentioned above.

```
function thisWorks()
{
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
    return false;
}

function thisDoesNotWork()
{
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

window.location.href works fine in all versions of Firefox, as does document.location.href  I think that there is something else in your code that is breaking things.

drop this in a blank page, if it works, it indicates there is something else wrong on your page.

```
<script>
  window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com/';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `window.location.replace` to jump to an anchor without register it in the browser history:

This [article](http://bytes.com/forum/thread587235.html) illustrates how to jump to an anchor and uses href as read-only property.

```
function navigateNext() 
{
    if (!window.location.hash) 
    {
        window.location.replace(window.location.href + unescape("#2"))
    } 
    else 
    {
        newItem = nextItem(window.location.hash)
        if (document.getElementById(newItem)) 
        {
            window.location.replace(stripHash(window.location) + "#" + newItem)
        } 
        else 
        {
            window.location.replace(stripHash(window.location) + "#1")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just `window.location.hash = "1"`?  All the replacing and stripping seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
Response.Write("<script type='text/javaScript'> window.location = '#myAnchor'; </script>";);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.hash = "#gallery";
```

Answer (score 0):

please add full javascript script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference I had the same problem.

onclick = "javascript: window.location('example.html');" didn't work under FF (latest)

I just had to rewrite to onclick = "javascript: window.location = 'example.html';" to get it working

Answer (score 0):

I just overcome the same problem. and the problem is not in javascript, but the href attribute on the `<a>` element.

my js code

```
function sebelum_hapus()
{
var setuju = confirm ("Anda akan menghapus data...")
if (setuju)
window.location = "index.php";
}
```

my previous html was

```
<a href="" onClick="sebelum_hapus();">Klik here</a>
```

and I update it to

```
<a href="#" onClick="sebelum_hapus();">Klik here</a>
```

or remove the href attribute

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

window.location.assign("link to next page") should work in both (chrome and firefox) browsers.

```js
window.location.assign("link to next page")
```

Answer (score -2):

Another option:

```
document.location.href ="..."
```