# Why Page is not redirected using javascript on using window.location and window.location.href

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, redirect

I am using a login system for my website.
What I am doing is that when the user clicks the submit button an ajax request is being executed to target php script which logs in the user and if user is logged in successfully then `echo's` back the message "login_successful" to the ajax request. By using `if` statement I check whether the message is "login_successful" `else` display the error.

If the message is "login_successful" the script redirect the user to the new page 'user.php' by using `window.location = 'user.php';
//I have also tried this.
window.location.href = 'user.php';`

But it doesn't work It simply stays on the login page and nothing happens.
but when i check the page source after logging in but no redirection takes place then i got a surprise that the source of the page is for user.php instead of login.php. Somehow `window.location` hasn't redirected the page but bring the source of user.php to login.php. It's all messed up and I couldn't solve the problem.

Here is the login function which performs the ajax request and then redirect the user-

```
function login()
{
    var e = _("email").value;// Grab the email input by the user.
    var p = _("password").value;// Grab the password input by the user.
    if(e === "" || p === "")// Check if they are empty.
    {
        _("status").innerHTML = "Fill out all the form data";//Display error message if fields are empty.
    }
    else
    {
        _("loginbtn").style.display = "none";// Hide the login button
        _("status").innerHTML = 'please wait ...';//Tell the user to wait while the script works.
        // Below id another function which is defined in other js file.
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "login.php"); //start the ajax request.
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function()// Wait for the request to be complete
        {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) === true) // Ensures if the response is recieved
            {
                var response = ajax.responseText;// Put the response in a variable
                if(response === 'login_successful')// Check if user is logged in succesfully.
                {
                    window.location = 'user.php';//Redirect the user to the new page.(Not working)
                }
                else
                {
                    _('status').innerHTML = response;// Display the response
                    _("loginbtn").style.display = "block";// Display the login button
                }
            }
        };
        ajax.send("e="+e+"&p="+p);
    }
}
```

I am using the latest version of chrome on a 64 bit windows machine.

**Update**

OK guys I have verified that the response via php script is 'login_successful' and it doesn't contains any line so that we can trim on it.

Comment: If you put some `alert` inside your `if(response === 'login_successful')`, it's works ?

Comment: May be response == 'login_successful' can help you

Comment: Ok, You mean like this `alert(response);`

Comment: @SunilPachlangia Why would that make a difference?

Comment: @UTKARSHVISHNOI His point is to put something inside the `if` to make sure you're getting there. You can also set a breakpoint in the Javascript debugger.

Comment: Because there is no need of type casting at all.string will be compared

Comment: @SunilPachlangia `===` doesn't do type casting `==` does.

Comment: i have tried that too what Sunil says it's not working. Don't worry I am sure it's error in my javascript but not in my php

Comment: @UTKARSHVISHNOI Yeah, doesn't matter what you put inside your alert. It's just like a test, because for me the problem is with your `===` (like @Sunil Pachlangia said...

Comment: @UTKARSHVISHNOI - You can try `window.open('yourURI', '_self');` too...

Comment: @BARMAR What do you mean? Could you be more specific???

Comment: The last time I helped someone with a problem like this, the problem was that `response` ended with a newline. Try `response = response.trim()` to remove extra whitespace.

Comment: already asked question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345807/window-location-does-not-work-on-chrome-browser]

Comment: @UTKARSHVISHNOI Try temporarily changing `var response = ajax.responseText;` to `var response = 'login_successful';`,  does it work ? if so, the problem is on `response`. Has @barmar said,  it may contain a new line.

Comment: @PedroLobito No it didnt work

Comment: I have also tried `window.open('user.php', '_self');` Unfortunately it is not working

Comment: @UTKARSHVISHNOI is `ajaxReturn(ajax) === true` ?, put an  `else` on `if(ajaxReturn(ajax) === true)` and log the `else` to console, any message ? if so, `ajaxReturn(ajax) is false`

Comment: @PedroLobito You mean i put console.log inside the else

Comment: yes, create an `else` for `if(ajaxReturn(ajax) === true)` and log anything to console. Any message there ? if so, your problem is on `ajaxReturn(ajax)`. Keep debugging like that until you find where the error is.

Comment: @PedroLobito No messages in console the problem still persists

Comment: OK i got the problem i used the `console.log` as @PedroLobito has told me on the `else` and it logged the word on the console. B8ut what to do now

Comment: Thanks everyone for contributing. It's working now.   The problem is inside this `(  )` braces. Their were 2 spacebars at the top of my php file therefore the `responseText` printed was `  login_successful` instead of 'login_successful'.

Answer (score 0):

check the result by alert in between response condition & use

```
window.location.href='correctfilepath.php';
```

correct path of file to be redirected. Check your user.php also as it will not print anything if it will have some error in code

Comment: he said he tried using `window.location.href` and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: ya..but user.php path may have been written wrong..../user.php if the file is not in the same directory

Comment: Listen up guys the file is in the same directory and i have tried `window.location` and `window.location.href' Its Still  not working

Comment: you are getting a successful result after comparing response==='login_successful'??

Comment: means a message is being alerted??

Comment: yeah the message is same as it should be "login _ successfull".

Answer (score 0):

if you use location i prefer to use a absolute path. Maybe this is your problem and a redirect will be working with this. For example:

```
location.href = '/user.php';
```

If you want to redirect to a url do it like this:

```
location.href = '//www.google.com';
```

(it will automatically use http or https based on the current scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the full URL for redirection

**window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/user.php"**

instead of **window.location = 'user.php';**

Edited:

**window.location = "//" + window.location.host + "/user.php"**

Javascript redirection works without the protocol (http or https) also.

Comment: i think it does I have tried the same in my other scripts and they work well.

Comment: But do they work on absolue url's within the same folder like for example for a php ahe named user.php can we write``window.location = ''user.php';

Answer (score 0):

```
if(response === 'login_successful')// Check if user is logged in succesfully.
                {
                    window.location = 'user.php';//Redirect the user to the new page.(Not working)
                }
                else
                {
                    _('status').innerHTML = response;// Display the response
                    _("loginbtn").style.display = "block";// Display the login button
                }
```

In the else block you had given  _('status').innerHTML = response; check that block is executing or not if its is executing then try to change the (=== as == )in the if condition hope it may work.

Comment: I have altered my code as you were saying but the problem still persists

Comment: Is that if block executing?