# window.location.href in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser

Can you please tell me why `window.location.href` is not working on firefox?

Code:

```
<script>

     function goToURL() {
           window.location.href('url');
     }

</script>
```

What can I use instead of `window.location.href` as an alternative?

Comment: Use it in what way, exactly? Please expand on your question - read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice for more information.

Comment: What are you trying to do? This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275092/windows-location-href-not-working-on-firefox3

Comment: This is really not an answerable question in its current form, as it doesn't really make sense.  You should state what you're trying to *achieve*, possibly giving your current code, and ask for advice of how to improve it.

Answer (score 5):

This should work in both IE and FireFox:

```
window.location.assign(url);
```

Comment: `replace()` will replace the current page in the history, whereas assigning to `href` doesn't.  `assign()` is a more appropriate alternative.

Comment: @Andy E - You're right. Updated.

Comment: Thank you! After many headaches, testing location.href (which works in IE and not FF), etc. this finally works in both as of today.

Answer (score 2):

You use it for example like this:

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.guffa.com';
```

I have verified that this code works in Firefox 3.6.12.

If that doesn't work for you, you have to be more specific in your question about what the exact problem is.

Answer (score 0):

use it with an assignment

```
window.location = "http://...";
```

anyway you should be more specific in your question

Comment: This does not work in the latest version of FF

Answer (score 0):

Here is answere for You:

[windows.location.href not working on Firefox3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275092/windows-location-href-not-working-on-firefox3)

Comment: That's not a good answer though. It might make it work in Firefox for some reason, but it stops working in some other browsers. Setting `window.location.href` works in Firefox, so there is something else that is the problem.

Comment: You are right, thanks for pointing this out.