# How to make a script redirect only once every time an appropriate page loads?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey, greasemonkey-4

I'm writing a Tampermonkey script that I want to use to redirect from `youtube.com/*` to a YouTube channel address.

```
window.addEventListener ("load", LocalMain, false);

function LocalMain () {
    location.replace("https://www.youtube.com/channel/*");
}
```

When the script is running it redirects to the channel URL but then keeps running and **continuously redirects**.

Comment: Try setting up a cookie for youtube named "hasRedirect" and if it is not defined, redirect. Otherwise, if it is already defined, don't redirect.

Comment: check if the url is `/channel/`, if not, redirect

Comment: Isaac Vidrine how would I do that?

Comment: Near duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675049/greasemonkey-add-parameters-to-url and many others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard, much **more efficient**, and much **faster performing** way to do this kind of redirect is to **tune the script's [metadata](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block)** to not even run on the redirected-to page.

Also, use `// @run-at document-start` for even better response.

So your script would become something like:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        YouTube, Redirect to my channel
// @match       https://www.youtube.com/*
// @exclude     https://www.youtube.com/channel/*
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

location.replace("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8VkNBOwvsTlFjoSnNSMmxw");
```

---

Also, for such "broad spectrum" redirect scripts, consider using `location.assign()` so that you or your user can recover the original URL in the history in case of an overzealous redirect.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if the current  `pathname` includes `channel` before reassigning a new href

```
function LocalMain () {

     if(!location.pathname.includes('/channel/')) {
        location.replace("https://www.youtube.com/channel/*");
     }
}
```

Also note you don't need to window load event to complete to do this

Answer (score 2):

You could check to see if the location contains 'channel', then return before you change the location.

```
window.addEventListener ("load", LocalMain, false);

function LocalMain () {
    if(location.href.indexOf('channel') === -1) return;
    location.replace("https://www.youtube.com/channel/*");
}
```

Comment: Don't think location object has a contains method

Comment: @charlietfl, thank you for the catch sometimes I load some convienience methods into my browser.  In this case it tripped me up.

Comment: OK...but edit still won't work... `location` is an object not string

Comment: @charlietfl, Ok checked it this time it works with the href property which is what I was thinking but not coding.  Thank you once again for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Is tampermonkey configured to run the script only when *not* on your channel URL?

If not... then your script might ironically be doing exactly what you want: running once each page load. And the script loads a new page.

You can fix this within the script, like this:

```js
window.addEventListener ('load', localMain, false);

function localMain () {
    if (location.href.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/channel/')) {
        return; // exit
    }
    location.replace('https://www.youtube.com/channel/*');
}
```