# PHP/SQL query Delete From doesn't work in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: php, sql, firefox

I have a weird issue than maybe someone had before.

I have a code to delete a row with an specific id (in my database) in a PHP file:

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){

    $bannerid = $_REQUEST['bannerid'];

    $sql = "DELETE FROM cc_homeslide WHERE id='$bannerid'";
    $conn->query($sql) === TRUE;

    echo "<script>document.location.href='home-slide.php'</script>" ;

}
```

EDIT: And this is my form code

```
<form class='form-delete' action='home-slide-actions.php?bannerid=". $row["id"]."' method='POST'>
 <button class='delete' type='submit' name='delete'>
  <i class='fa fa-trash-o fa-2x'></i>
 </button>
</form>
```

This code works in Safari and Google Chrome but doesn't work in Mozilla Firefox.

Any idea bout what is going on here?

Comment: what does your form look like? It is possible that you have an malformed form/input elements, and Safari/Chrome ignore the error, but Firefox causes the error to not post the form correctly.

Comment: Try the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275092/windows-location-href-not-working-on-firefox3

Comment: What part of it doesn't work?

Comment: Hi, I have added the form code... Brian the query is not working but the script yes, anyway I am going to move everything to window.location

Comment: Can you just give it a shot to use something like
'"DELETE FROM cc_homeslide WHERE id='.$bannerid.'";'
add those dots in your query, google it, your way, you are just passing the string $bannerid and not the value of variable